# Socket.io Configuration Problem on Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets

Browser error message:
polling.js:298     GET http://34.68.254.120:8081/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Odf_1cx 404 (Not Found)

So I am able to start my server, but the client-side socket connection is not finding the server.

Client HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.2/socket.io.js"></script>
```

(I've also pointed it directly to the local socket.io directory, same error)

Client JS:

```
var socket = io();
```

(I've also tried putting in the exact server IP address and port, same error)

Server node.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);
```

(I've tried this about 3 different ways, including exactly how I have it set up on a working server, same error)

I'm on port 8081, and I've checked that the port is allowed through firewalls. I've also tried port 8080 which I know works, and I have the same error here.

It seems like some sort of configuration problem. My node_modules folder includes express, socket.io, node, etc. I've tried deleting all contents and re-uploading from my git repository. But perhaps I should delete all socket.io files and re-install through npm? I'm unsure how that might help, though, as I see all of the files are there.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It turns out I had

```
app.listen(port, () => {
```

rather than

```
server.listen(port, () => {
```

in my server-side node code. Silly mistake.